# XNA 2d drawing library

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, 2d

Is there any free **XNA 2d drawing library**?

I would like support for common **drawing operation** and **effects**.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one that I know of(and I spent a good while looking). Your best bet is just to use 3d primitive-drawing (as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196414.aspx)). Or, if you want to draw lines, you could just take a 1x1 pixel sprite and expand the source-rectangle as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PrimitiveBatch class in the Nuclex Framework:
http://nuclexframework.codeplex.com/.

It's in the namespace Nuclex.Graphics.Batching.